# Regex: Ignore + (plus sign) at EOL?

Tags: regex, grep, code-analysis

I'm trying to grep through a *large* amount old AS/400 code (CL, COBOL, etc). There are situations where commands are "wrapped" to the next line with a `+` sign. You can literally have a break in the middle of an identifier and continue it on the next line.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM LIBR+
ARY/FILE
```

But the same code could be written this way (this break could be anywhere):

```
SELECT * FROM LI+
BRARY/FILE
```

In this case, I'd be looking to grep with something like `'LIBRARY\/'` to find that identifier.

Ignoring newlines with regex is easy enough, but how do I ignore the `+` as well?

Comment: You might remove `/\+\r?\n/g` in your codes, and pipe the result of that operation into the grep.

Answer (score 0):

If you can ignore new lines, you can ignore the plus sign followed by a new line ;)
Think about escaping the plus as is it a regex character.

Answer (score 0):

One way using `sed` and `grep`:

```
< file.txt sed ':a;N;$!ba; s/+\n//g' | grep "LIBRARY/"
```